# How to make WiFi hotspot without password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

How do I make a mobile hotspot without a password on my machine? I've seen posts talking about `wlan`, but I don't even know how that works, and it doesn't even finish the command. Running `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` just makes it wait for a bit, and then it finally outputs this:

`The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.`

And then there's going to do it through Control Panel `(Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> Properties -> Sharing -> Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection)`, which seems to work until you notice that searching on the Wi-Fi networks on another device that there isn't a new Wi-Fi network to connect to.

I don't know how to do this, and searchin around on here for answers, it's the same answer that doesn't make any sense, and/or doesn't work. So How do I make a mobile hotspot on my Windows 10 machine that is passwordless?

*(Note for mods: Do NOT close this question unless you know someone else has the same problem as me. This is a completely original post, and that post you linked to this post isn't the same problem that I have, that's something different!! There was a post about netsh without a password, and starting wlan still won't work for me! )*

Comment: You can not create WiFi hotspot/access point without password on Windows platform. It is impossible by implementation/design.

Comment: Man there's gotta be a way to do this

Comment: WiFi is a subset of `wlan` (wireless LAN)

Comment: @WolfyRed No, there is no.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked all my machines here and all have Hotspot capability. Windows 10 and 11 do not allow Hotspots without passwords. Microsoft has completely secured Hotspot setup.

To remove this security would be a gross failure in workstation security.

So you cannot do what you want. Sorry but that is the way it is.